# highchart datalabel one value is missing in label

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

i have highchart graph api similar to pasted fiddle link, the problem
    is number is missing in few stacked column( example in fiddle **decission** line one label value is missing) could anyone help on this why
    this is happening

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        inverted:true,
        height: 200
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked column chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Pending', 'Further', 'Decision']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        //max:100,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'center',
        x: -30,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        floating: false,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                crop:false,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                style: {
                    textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data:[3, 2, 1], 
        name:'Today'
    }, {
        data:[2, 2, 19], 
        name:'1 Day'
    }, {
        data:[14, 2, 22], 
        name:'2 Days'
    },{
        data:[6, 2, 18], 
        name:'3 Days'
    },{
        data:[10, 2, 537], 
        name:'>3 Days'
    }]
});
```

});
http://jsfiddle.net/g6wsd1hm/

Comment: On the jsfiddle I see all values for "decision" -> 537, 18, 22, 19, 1. I also see all 5 labels on top. Could you elaborate?

Comment: fiddle link in firefox browser its working in chrome browser its not working.. but from actual application its not working in both browsers

Comment: none of your point is missing, since the value is too small that's why you can't see that. if you hover on decision line carefully you can see all your values on that stack

Comment: @NishithChaturvedi i agree on tooltip am able to see value but still i want number to be shown on that each stacked column

Comment: enough space needed there to show that

Comment: It is possible to set [allowOverlap](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.allowOverlap) to true to show all labels, but as Nishith mentioned - there need to be space to see them or they will not be readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I change stacking to percent ,all labels are visible. minPointLength is set to make minimum column stacks width for a relatively less number

use following :

```
 plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'percent',
            minPointLength:10 //this needs to added
                }
              }
```

Fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/g6wsd1hm/1/)